# Java Al cambiar una parte de la cadena no se modifica (método replace() de String)

Tags: java, string, str-replace

Estoy procesando texto, quiero quitar varios elementos como signos de puntuación, exclamaciones, urls, entre otras cosas, en este caso quiero sustituir los  &# (acentos, su símbolo en HTML).

Intento cambiar una parte de una cadena usando el método replace(), de la clase String en Java, pero no me sustituye la subcadena deseada, como he podido comprobar imprimiendo la cadena justo después de hacer el replace.

Supónganse que esta es la línea donde quiero eliminar el &#:

*LOOOOL TA PHOTO =D !tu as aim&#233*

Y este es el código que he hecho y con el que no consigo el objetivo:

```
public class Procesamiento {
    private String cadena_;

    Procesamiento(String archivo) throws Exception{
        FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        FileWriter ficheroPreVocabulario = new FileWriter("/home/alien/Escritorio/PLN_IAA/preVocabulario.txt");
        PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(ficheroPreVocabulario);
        while((cadena_=b.readLine())!=null) {
            String a = cadena_;
            String[] linea = a.split("\\s+"); //tienes que dobleescapar, el primer \ escapa al segundo \, si solo pusieras un \ escaparías la s, es decir, se trataria la s como caracter literal, y como no quieres eso,quieres indicar que tiene un significado especial 
            for(int i=0;i<linea.length;i++) {
                eliminaHashtags(linea[i]);
            }
            pw1.println(String.join(" ", linea));
        }
        b.close();
    }

    void eliminaHashtags(String cadena_) throws Exception {
        if(cadena_.contains("&#")) {
            cadena_.replace("&#","");
            System.out.println(" la cadena_ despues de eliminar  hashtag  " + cadena_); // Lo he probado, no elimina el &#
        }
    }
}
```

Todos los imports se han hecho y el programa no se queja de esa parte. Se agradece ayuda. Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Los strings son constantes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) según la documentación. no vas a poder cambiar su valor, lo que tenés que hacer es capturar el valor de retorno de la función [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-).

```
if(cadena_.contains("&#")) {
  cadena_ = cadena_.replace("&#","");
  System.out.println(" la cadena_ despues de eliminar  hashtag  " + cadena_); // Lo he probado, no elimina el &#
}
```

Cualquier método que modifique el valor original de la cadena de texto vas a tener que asignarlo a una variable. El objeto original no va a cambiar.